# Repeat input field for email in selenium using random string

Tags: java, selenium

I've written a test case that creates random emails to be input to email fields

```
package DDselenium.general;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

public class GenerateData {
public String generateRandomString(int length){
    return RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(length);
}

public String generateRandomNumber(int length){
    return RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(length);
}

public String generateRandomAlphaNumeric(int length){
    return RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(length);
}

public String generateStringWithAllobedSplChars(int length,String allowdSplChrs){
    String allowedChars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" +   //alphabets
            "1234567890"; //numbers
    return RandomStringUtils.random(length, allowedChars);
}

public String generateEmail(int length) {
    String allowedChars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" +   //alphabets
            "1234567890";   //numbers

    String email="";
    String temp=RandomStringUtils.random(length,allowedChars);
    email=temp.substring(0,temp.length()-9)+"@test.org";
    return email;
}

public String generateUrl(int length) {
    String allowedChars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" +   //alphabets
            "1234567890"; //Numbers
    String url="";
    String temp=RandomStringUtils.random(length,allowedChars);
    url=temp.substring(0,3)+"."+temp.substring(4,temp.length()-4)+"."+temp.substring(temp.length()-3);
    return url;
}
}
```

I generate the random email as such

```
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(genData.generateEmail(30));
```

The issue I'm running into is that I have a field for confirm email so the actual code is like this

```
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(genData.generateEmail(30));
driver.findElement(By.id("emailconfirm")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("emailconfirm")).equals("email");
```

The problem is, I don't know how to get the emailconfirm element to duplicate whats in the email element.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is purely a Java problem, and has nothing to do with Selenium!

```
String email = genData.generateEmail(30);
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(email);
driver.findElement(By.id("emailconfirm")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("emailconfirm")).sendKeys(email);
```